# Why won't my ReactJS / Typescript project deploy on Vercel?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, git, next.js, vercel

I have a React portfolio that uses Typescript for the components, created it a few months ago and it was working fine. I made pushes to my main git branch recently and even though my project runs smoothly on the local host development server using npm, I get this error in Vercel when trying to deploy after pushing changes to the main branch:

---

```
Failed to compile.
./components/HeroSection.tsx:52:11
Type error: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: LinkProps | Readonly<LinkProps>): Link', gave the following error.
    Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: LinkProps, context: any): Link', gave the following error.
    Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
  50 |           duration={500}
  51 |         >
> 52 |           <HiArrowDown size={35} className="animate-bounce" />
     |           ^
  53 |         </Link>
  54 |       </div>
  55 |     </section>
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1
```

---

I'm getting this error for this HeroSection.tsx component file (but has problems with my other Typescript components too):

---

```
"use client" // this is a client component
import React from "react"
import Image from "next/image"
import { Link } from "react-scroll/modules"
import { HiArrowDown } from "react-icons/hi"

const HeroSection = () => {
  return (
    <section id="home">
      <div className="flex flex-col text-center items-center justify-center animate-fadeIn animation-delay-2 my-10 py-16 sm:py-32 md:py-48 md:flex-row md:space-x-4 md:text-left">
        <div className="md:mt-2 md:w-1/2">
          <Image
            src="/headshot-image.png"
            alt=""
            width={325}
            height={325}
            className="rounded-full shadow-2xl"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="md:mt-2 md:w-3/5">
          <h1 className="text-4xl font-bold mt-6 md:mt-0 md:text-7xl">Hi, I&#39;m Jordan!</h1>
          <p className="text-lg mt-4 mb-6 md:text-2xl">
            I&#39;m an aspiring{" "}
            <span className="font-semibold text-teal-600">
              Software Engineer{" "}
            </span>
            based in Los Angeles, CA. I enjoy creating software that
            makes life easier and more meaningful.
          </p>
          <Link
            to="projects"
            className="text-neutral-100 font-semibold px-6 py-3 bg-teal-600 rounded shadow hover:bg-teal-700"
            activeClass="active"
            spy={true}
            smooth={true}
            offset={-100}
            duration={500}
          >
            Projects
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="flex flex-row items-center text-center justify-center ">
        <Link
          to="about"
          activeClass="active"
          spy={true}
          smooth={true}
          offset={-100}
          duration={500}
        >
          <HiArrowDown size={35} className="animate-bounce" />
        </Link>
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default HeroSection
```

---

I tried resetting my package-lock.json file to update all my dependencies and experimented with editing different parts of my components but I still get that same Vercel deployment error every time.

I also isolated the problem doing a gitignore on the .tsx files to see if that was the problem and I ended up getting the deployment to work (with the final deployed page not rendering since the .tsx files were ignored in the git push of course)

Any ideas on what could be the problem here?

Comment: <HiArrowDown/> What if wrap this icon inside a span?